# Has the feminization of the labor force continued after WW1?

Tags: world-war-one

I've read that during the World War I, the labor force has experienced a strong feminization, in order to compensate the lack of men (engaged in the army).

At the end of the war, has the rate of women in the labor force dropped ? If yes, has it returned to its 1914 level ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not a good source, but you might want to read "[Fall of Gigants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_Giants)" by Ken Follett, a novel based on sources, which refers to the subject you are interesting in.

By logic, this (feminization of industry) could never drop to rate as of 1914. The main reason was than many men died or was much injured. Not only because of lack of male workers, but also lack of male heads-of-families.

I can't find any numbers, but if I do, I'll update the answer.